# How to handle dependency injection when using a common base controller for multiple controllers in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a UserController and a BaseController with some functions and dependencies injected as below. The BaseController is shared between multiple controllers. But All the controllers do not need all the injected dependencies from the BaseController. Controller1 Needs dependencies D1 and D2 but Controller2 requires only D1 from BaseController. How can I achieve this?

In the below code, UserController does not require the injected webHostEnvironment from the base but I need to inject it as it present in BaseController else Visual Studio throws compiler error of missing dependency. Please let me know if additional details are required to resolve the issue.

**UserController**

```
using MyApp.Data;
using MyApp.Models;
using MyApp.Models.ViewModels;
using MyApp.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UserController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        private readonly ILogger<UserController> logger;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender emailSender;

        public UserController(  ApplicationDbContext db,
                                ILogger<UserController> logger,
                                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                                IEmailSender emailSender,
                                IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment) : base (userManager, webHostEnvironment)
        {
            this.db = db;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
            this.emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var userList = userManager.Users;
            return View(userList);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Read(string? id)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return RecordNotFound();
            }
            UserViewModel model = new()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Email = user.Email,
                PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
            };
            return View(model);
        }
    //And Some more Action Methods for the controller
    }
}
```

**BaseController**

```
using MyApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Utilities
{
    [Authorize]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        protected readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
        
        public BaseController(  UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            
        }

        [HttpGet] [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RecordNotFound()
        {
            TempData[HelperStatic.ErrorMessage] = HelperStatic.recordNotFoundMsg;
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveNew()
        {
            TempData[HelperStatic.SuccessMessage] = HelperStatic.recordSavedMsg;
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        
        //And Many other Reusable Methods for all controllers
    }
}
```

Comment: If your base controller needs some dependencies in case a base method is called, you have to inject all needed ones. If your derived class doesn't need those base functionality why do you derive from it? Or you should make multiple finer grained base classes to derive from the specific from for each case.

Comment: Can you post more detailed information about the compiler error? Based on your code, I create a Asp.net 5 application, after adding the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;` reference, the code works well on my side, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khxvB.png) (as we can see the code execute to the break point).

Comment: @ZhiLv Please find the error message screenshot here when I remove a dependency
https://ibb.co/ThBFW99

Comment: @Oliver Sure That can be done, Since I, am dealing with Identity Controllers, I was hoping to maintain one BaseController for All Identity related Controllers.

Comment: @ahp Is it an option to provide `null` as the dependency for the `BaseController` constructor? It is unclear if the dependency is optional or required.

Comment: @Progman I tried giving Null It doesn't give any error but provides a warning. If I don't give the dependency it gives an error.  Please see the screenshot when providing null https://ibb.co/z7zbPVy

Comment: @ahp You have to define for yourself if the dependency should be required or optional for the `BaseController`. In case it is optional, you can use `null` as the value. In case it is required, you have to use an actual instance of the dependency (or let it injected by some framework for you).

Comment: @Progman Yes I can ignore the warning, but I have a weird feeling something is not right when the compiler is not happy :-)

Comment: @ahp The compiler shouldn't show a warning that the argument is `null` unless there is a reason to do so (like `[NotNull]` attributes). Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the `BaseController` class and a screenshot of the full complete warning you are getting when your `UserController` class using `null` as the argument for one of the dependencies of the `BaseController` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem what you have here is too much going on in your base controller.

If you have actions within the base controller that are not applicable to all, then they are living in the wrong place.

For example (from what you've given), this action looks like it should maybe live e.g. on an error controller:

```
[HttpGet] [HttpPost]
public IActionResult RecordNotFound()
{
    TempData[HelperStatic.ErrorMessage] = HelperStatic.recordNotFoundMsg;
    return View("Index");
}
```

And you redirect to 'Error/RecordNotFound' rather than having this live within every inheriting controller.

You cannot have dependencies on your base constructor that are not also injected on sub classes.  If this is causing you a problem, it's because there's too much going on in the base!